# set watcher on props of vuejs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4, vue-component

I have created datepicker vuejs component.

I have set two date picker in page to select start date and end date. So startDate and endDate of one datepicker is depend on value of another. So for that, I need to set watcher on selected value.

It was working fine with VueJS (< 2.3.0) using `this.$emit('input', value)`. But in VueJS (2.4.4), it is not working.

I'm very poor in front-end development. So I got nothing even after spending two days on vuejs. I just come to know that it is just because of vue version > 2.2.6.

If anyone know the solution, it will be realy very much helpful for me.

Here is my code.

**DatePicker.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
        <input size="16" type="text" readonly>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        twoWay: true,
        props: ['slctd', 'startDate', 'endDate'],
        mounted: function () {
            var self = this;
            $(this.$el).datetimepicker({
                format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
                autoclose: true,
                minView: 2,
                maxView: 3,
                daysShort: true,
                initialDate: this.slctd,
                startDate: this.startDate,
                endDate: this.endDate,
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                var value = new Date(ev.date.valueOf()).toString('MM/dd/yyyy');
                self.$emit('input', value);
            });
        },
        watch: {
            slctd: function (value) {
                console.log('watch:value ' + value);
                $(this.$el).find("input").val(value);
            },
            startDate: function (value) {
                console.log('watch:start ' + value);
                $(this.$el).datetimepicker('setStartDate', value);
            },
            endDate: function (value) {
                console.log('watch:end ' + value);
                $(this.$el).datetimepicker('setEndDate', value);
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**JS**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('component-date-picker', require('./components/DatePicker.vue'));
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        queries: {
            start_date: '10/04/2017',
            end_date: '10/05/2017',
        }
    },
});
```

**HTML**

```
<component-date-picker v-bind:end-date="queries.end_date" v-bind:slctd="queries.start_date" v-model="queries.start_date"></component-date-picker>
<component-date-picker v-bind:start-date="queries.start_date" v-bind:slctd="queries.end_date" v-model="queries.end_date"></component-date-picker>
```

- VueJS - 2.2.6 (working)
- VueJS - 2.4.4 (not working)

**I have also tried this too. But didn't get success**

**HTML**

```
<component-date-picker v-bind:end-date="queries.end_date" v-bind:slctd="queries.start_date" v-model="queries.start_date" v-on:input="set_start_date"></component-date-picker>
<component-date-picker v-bind:start-date="queries.start_date" v-bind:slctd="queries.end_date" v-model="queries.end_date" v-on:input="set_end_date"></component-date-picker>
```

**JS**

```
methods: {
    set_start_date: function(value){
        console.log('called');
        this.queries.start_date = value;
    },
    set_end_date: function(value){
        this.queries.end_date = value;
    },
}
```

In this code, I method was called and I was getting 'called' in console. But watcher of component not working. It should work as startDate/endDate is changed in these methods. I don't know what is the new working concept of VueJS 2.4.4.

**Solved**

It was my stupid mistake due to lack of knowledge in front-end. I was re-creating queries object in `create` method of vue root instance. And in previous code, there was nothing in `create` so it was working fine.

Here is my mistake

**JS**

```
created: function () {
    /* my mistake starts */
    this.queries = queryString.parse(location.search, {arrayFormat: 'bracket'});
    /* my mistake ends */
    this.queries.start_date = (this.queries.start_date) ? this.queries.start_date : null;
    this.queries.end_date = (this.queries.end_date) ? this.queries.end_date : null;
},
```

Comment: Which dateimepicker are you using??

Comment: [http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: Seems to be working for me: https://codepen.io/kevlai22/pen/gGXMPQ

Comment: @kevguy It's not working for me. I'm using webpack. Is it affects? Anyways, I'm also surprised with your code because it is clearly said that we have to define v-on:input="" on component on vuejs version after 2.3.0. Can you please look at [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/upgrading-vue-2.3/)?

Comment: Try using `import` instead of `require`. What I did was basically copying all your code to codepen and added all the depenencies. And which part of your link said anything about `v-on:input=""`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155878/discussion-between-akshay-vaghasiya-and-kevguy).